# AppSync: create resource with a sub type

Tags: aws-appsync

Good evening everyone,

I'm using the AWS AppSync "Create Resources" option, "Define new Type". So I wanted to add a new type.

The type I want to add has a sub type inside a list. Here is my example of schema:

```
type Object {
   id:ID!
   sub_objects: [SubObject]
}

type SubObject {
   id:ID!
}
```

However, I'm having the following error:

You must provide exactly 1 object type definition.

So, how can I use this feature, "Create Resource" with a resource that has sub objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it.

I've started creating the resources from the sub object up, one by one.